# finding the greatest perfect square dividing an integer

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

how can we find the greatest integer which is a perfect square and which divides an integer? I believe factorisation can be used here but am not sure how to get the result out of it for all prime, non-prime, and also integers which are themselves perfect square(e.g 1296) ?
Thanks.

Comment: If $n = \prod_i p_i^{\alpha_i}$ then $k = \prod_i p_i^{f(\alpha_i)}$ where $f(x)$ is the greatest even number smaller than $x$, i.e. $f(x) = 2\left\lfloor\frac{x}{2}\right\rfloor$.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A008833

Comment: you can use the sum of two squares to find the greatest perfect square that divides an integer $N$ without having to factor $N$. The details can be found here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3064068/can-the-sum-of-two-squares-be-used-to-determine-if-a-number-is-square-free?rq=1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Say that you are given the integer $n$ and want to find the largest perfect square $k$ such that $k \mid n$.

First, find the prime factorization of $n$:
$$n = p_1^{e_1} \cdots p_m^{e_m}$$
Let 
$$k = p_{1}^{e_1'} \cdots p_{m}^{e_m'}$$
where $e_m'$ is the largest even integer smaller than or equal to $e_m$, which will make $k$ the largest perfect square which divides $n$.

For example
$$1296 = 2^4 \cdot 3^4$$
and both exponents are even, so you get the same number.

Since
$$1 609 699 = 7^3 \cdot 13 \cdot 19^2$$
the largest perfect square which divides this is $7^2 \cdot 19^2 = 17689$.

And
$$3458 = 2 \cdot 7 \cdot 13 \cdot 19$$
has no exponents larger than one, so the largest perfect square which divides it is 1.